# What am I doing wrong when setting up socket.io in angular

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

So i am trying to use socket.io with my controller, but for some reason I cannot get it setup I tried many different things, but cant seem to find that sweet spot. Heres my setup:

```
       var main = angular.module("main", []);

  main.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
         var socket = io.connect();
           return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        })
    }
};
});

    main.controller('Triv', ['$scope', 'socket','$http','$interval',
   '$timeout', function ($scope, $http,$interval,socket, $timeout) {

   ......   })]);
```

Comment: Please provide a proper problem statement. *"can't find sweetspot"* tells us next to nothing. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: Lol, sorry I wish I could. I can't figure out how to set it up. I have nothing else really to show than this, because it wont work or start up at all through my angular app

Comment: It works perfectly through javascript in my html connecting to my server though. Just not in my angular controller

Comment: did you include socket.io.js ? :)

Comment: What doesn't work? You aren't mentioning any errors or any troubleshooting information. We can't play 20 questions when you don't provide details

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with gulp managed bower installed socket.io.
What I did is I created a symlink in my script source directory

`socket.io.js -> ../../bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js`

which forced inclusion of socket.io.js at the end of script list